# How to compute the conditional expected value of a geometric brownian motion?

Tags: modeling, brownian-motion

I'm working on a project, and I have to use the cumulative and conditional expected value of the variations of a stock following a Geometric Brownian Motion.

I know that the cumulative is as follows :
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbb{1}_{ \frac{S_{i+1}}{S_{i}} < z}\right] = \mathbb{P} \left[ \frac{S_{i+1}}{S_{i}} < z \right] = \Phi\left(\frac{\log(z) - (r- \frac{\sigma^2}{2})(t_{i+1}-t_i)}{\sigma \sqrt{t_{i+1}-t_i}}\right)
$$

$\Phi$ being the standard normal distribution cumulative function.

But I couldn't find the expression of the conditional expected value : 
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{S_{i+1}}{S_i} 1_{\frac{S_{i+1}}{S_i}<z}\right] $$

Comment: I think conditional expection is a more usual way to describe this.

Comment: @SRKX No sorry, I don't think that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ok then I changed it back, but aren't you looking to compute *the expectation of the return give the return is below $z$*?

Comment: @SRKX Yes, that's what I'm looking for

Comment: Well then isn't that the definition of conditional expectation?

Comment: @SRKX Actually I'm trying to implement a pricing method using this paper : http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.250.3906 and they use both the terms "partial" and "conditional" to describe that same expected value (check out page 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
E\bigg(\frac{S_{i+1}}{S_i}\mathbb{I}_{\frac{S_{i+1}}{S_i} < z}\bigg) &=zE\bigg(\mathbb{I}_{\frac{S_{i+1}}{S_i} < z}\bigg)-E\bigg(\Big(z-\frac{S_{i+1}}{S_i}\Big)\mathbb{I}_{\frac{S_{i+1}}{S_i} < z}\bigg) \\
&=zP\bigg(\frac{S_{i+1}}{S_i}<z\bigg)-E\bigg(\Big(z-\frac{S_{i+1}}{S_i}\Big)^+\bigg).
\end{align*}
Then you can compute the expectation using the put option pricing formula.

Alternatively, note that
\begin{align*}
\frac{S_{i+1}}{S_i} &= e^{(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(t_{i+1}-t_i) + \sigma (W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i})}\\
&=e^{(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(t_{i+1}-t_i) + \sigma \sqrt{t_{i+1}-t_i} \xi},
\end{align*}
where $\xi$ is a standard normal random variable. Then $\frac{S_{i+1}}{S_i}<z$ is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
\xi <\frac{\ln z-(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(t_{i+1}-t_i)}{\sigma \sqrt{t_{i+1}-t_i}}.
\end{align*}
Let 
\begin{align*}
d_2 = -\frac{\ln z-(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(t_{i+1}-t_i)}{\sigma \sqrt{t_{i+1}-t_i}}.
\end{align*}
We then have that
\begin{align*}
E\bigg(\frac{S_{i+1}}{S_i}\mathbb{I}_{\frac{S_{i+1}}{S_i} < z}\bigg) &=
\int_{-\infty}^{-d_2}e^{(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(t_{i+1}-t_i) + \sigma \sqrt{t_{i+1}-t_i} x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{-d_2}e^{r(t_{i+1}-t_i) }\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\big(x - \sigma \sqrt{t_{i+1}-t_i}\big)^2}{2}}dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{-d_2- \sigma \sqrt{t_{i+1}-t_i}}e^{r(t_{i+1}-t_i) }\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx\\
&=e^{r(t_{i+1}-t_i) }\Phi(-d_1),
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
d_1 = d_2+ \sigma \sqrt{t_{i+1}-t_i}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I guess this is the right answer, thank you.

Comment: Note that I have changed the definitions for $d_1$ and $d_2$ so that they are consistent with the Black-Scholes formula defintions

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the partial expectation of $\frac{S_{i+1}}{S_i}$. Since $\frac{S_{i+1}}{S_i}$ is lognormally distributed, you can use the following result:

For a lognormal random variable $X \sim LND(m,v^2)$,
$$ E(X | X < z) = E[X] \Phi\left( \frac{\log(z)-m-v^2}{v} \right) $$
In your case, $m = (r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2) (t_{i+1}-t_{i})$, $v^2 = \sigma^2 (t_{i+1}-t_{i})$, and $E[X] = S_i e{(r+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2) (t_{i+1}-t_{i})}$.

You can then use the fact that $\mathbb{E}[X|X<z] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}_{X<z} X]}{\mathbb{P}(X<z)}$ to get the desired expression.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but $\mathbb{E}[X|X<z] \neq \mathbb{E}[X\mathbb{I}_{X<z}]$ right? The first being conditional expectation and the second being called partial expectation apparently?

Comment: Yes, the two are different. The two are related by $\mathbb{E}[X|X<z] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}_{X<z} X]}{\mathbb{P}(X<z)}$. I'll add that part to my answer